# Problema em usar include php pastas diferentes

Tags: php, html, materialize

Primeiramente peço desculpas por não conseguir me expressar corretamente, estou aprendendo php ainda e me deparei com o seguinte problema.
Estou montando um site para estudos e na na raiz criei as pastas:

- css (onde fica o arquivo do materialize que preciso chamar)
- template (onde criei um arquivo chamado **`cabecalho.php`** e nele guardo
  a chamada ao arquivo de css do materialize e o meu navbar)
- Tarefas (onde criei o arquivo **`tarefa.php`** que por include chamo o
  **`cabecalho.php`** na pasta template e tenho o problema).

Na pasta raiz tenho o **`index.php`**

No **`index.php`** eu dou o seguinte include:

```
include ('template/cabecalho.php');
```

Ele então carrega o meu cabeçalho fazendo a chamada ao arquivo css do materialize e minha navbar.
No arquivo cabecalho.php chamo o arquivo css do materialize da seguinte maneira:

```
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
```

Ate ai tudo perfeito, o meu index carrega normalmente.

Meu problema acontece quando vou acessar o arquivo **`tarefa.php`**, quando eu dou include no **`cabecalho.php`** ele não carrega o arquivo do materialize ficando totalmente desconfigurada minha navbar e não carregando a framework.

No **`tarefa.php`** meu include ficou assim:

```
include ('../template/cabecalho.php');
```

Com isso ele carrega a navbar mais não o arquivo .css do materialize.

Seguem prints:

[image: Pasta raiz no windows]

[image: projeto]

Comment: Isso acontece porque os arquivos estão no mesmo nível, mas em diretórios diferentes, você só precisa mudar 'css/materialize', para '../css/materialize'

Comment: Fazendo isso da certo no arquivo tarefa.php porem no index.php fica desconfigurado já que ele chama o mesmo cabecalho.php e ai não consegue acessar o arquivo do materialize que esta dentro da pasta css na raiz. Estou em busca de uma solução que funcione para ambos

Comment: Bom, não consegui entender muito bem como tu faz as inclusões, mas pelo que vi essa ordem não tem sentido nem necessidade de ser feita, porque incluir um arquivo que vai incluir outro ? a partir do momento que é dado um include, o que estiver no arquivo incluido passa a ser parte do arquivo que solicitou a inclusão, logo, se incluir na index, teria que apontar como se cabecalho.php fosse parte da index.

Comment: Pode tirar print das suas pastas de arquivos?

Comment: E meio confuso e provavelmente não seja a forma correta de se fazer, mais o que estou fazendo e o seguinte, o arquivo index.php esta na raiz e o arquivo tarefas.php esta dentro da pasta tarefas. Ambos dão include no cabecalho.php que esta dentro da pasta template. Ai vem o problema por que o arquivo cabecalho.php chama o arquivo materialize.css que esta dentro da pasta css. So que como o arquivo index.php e tarefas.php estão em diretórios diferentes acabo tendo erro na chamada do arquivo materialize.css dentro do arquivo cabecalho.php

Comment: Adicionei 2 prints na pergunta, não consigo adicionar mais por minha reputação ser baixa.

Comment: Tente assim: href="/css/materialize.min.css"

Comment: Na index, voce inclui tarefas.php, em tarefas.php voce inclui cabecalho.php, e no cabeçalho você inclui o css/materialize, é isso  ?

Comment: Tanto no index.php (que esta na raiz) quanto no tarefa.php (que esta na pasta tarefa) eu dou um include no cabecalho.php que fica na pasta template. Ai no cabecalho.php que so tenho html chamo o arquivo materialize.css que fica dentro da pasta css. Olhando pela print da estrutura da para entender. O problema e que com isso quando abro o tarefa.php no navegador ele não consegue localizar o caminho do materialize.css

Comment: Coloque uma variavel no inicio das paginas (antes do include cabecalho) $pagina="index" na index.php e $pagina="tarefa" na tarefa.php. Na cabecalho.php faça um if else. If ($pagina=="tarefa"){ ../css/materialize  }else{ css/materialize

Comment: Eu evito esse problema colocando tudo fora de pastas, só deixo dentro de pastas as imagens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coloque uma variável `$pagina` nas paginas index.php e tarefa.php

**index.php**

```
<?php
 $pagina="index";
 include ('template/cabecalho.php');
```

**tarefa.php**

```
<?php
 $pagina="tarefa";
 include ('../template/cabecalho.php');
```

**cabecalho.php**

```
 if ($pagina=="tarefa"){

    echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>';

 }

 if ($pagina=="index"){

    echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>';

 }
```

**Ou se for aplicável**

```
 if ($pagina=="tarefa"){

    echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>';

 }else{

    echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>';

 }
```

> claro que se pode fazer de outras formas dependendo do seu código:

```
if ($pagina=="tarefa"){ 
   $link="../css/materialize.min.css";
}else{ 
   $link="css/materialize.min.css";
}

  echo "<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='".$link."'  media='screen,projection'/>";
```

Ou fora do php

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $link ?>"  media="screen,projection"/>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente o que eu queria. No caso adaptei a 3° opção que montou no meu projeto e funcionou perfeito. Novamente muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Sabendo sua estrutura de pastas:

```
/
.../template/
         .../cabecario.php
.../tarefas/
        .../tarefas.php
.../css/
    .../materialize.min.css
```

> index.php

```
include 'tarefas/tarefas.php'
```

> tarefas.php

```
include 'template/cabecario.php';
```

> cabecario.php

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
```

Todos são parte de `index.php`, então todos os apontamentos devem sair como se fossem de `index.php`.

Meu index.php com essa sequencia:

```
<html>
    <head>
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não e a solução que procurava mais me ajudou em outros pontos, pelo que percebi meu problema esta mais na organização. O que eu queria e que o index so chama-se o cabecalho.php para carregar o materialize.css e a mesma coisa com  o tarefas.php ele so deveria carregar o materialize. So que dando include no tarefas.php no index.php eu vou chamar o conteudo do tarefas.php para o index.php. Vou tentar me organizar melhor aqui e procurar uns tutorias de organização, obrigado pela ajuda mais ja me orientou bem no meu erro.

Comment: Pesquise por design patterns, se quiser se aprofundar mais pesquise por PHPOO e estruturas MVC, pode parecer meio difícil e confuso no começo, mas depois que entender o conceito sua vida nunca mais vai ser a mesma kk.

Comment: obrigado, ja vou iniciar =)

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho melhor você sempre ir pra raiz do servidor, ai a partir dela você usa o caminho.

/css/materialize.min.css">

Isso é uma boa prática caso você for chamar este arquivo de varias pastas diferentes, ai nunca vai se perder por causa da pasta atual ;).